# Excel: Sort cell base on specific text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have something like this.

[image]

I want to sort it to be something like;

[image]

is there a function to do this in excel? Like sorting the data base on the `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, using a helper column. However, you seem to have two criteria in your question:

- Count the amount of `x` characters. This, you can achieve using a `CountIF()`.
- Sort, according to the location of the `x` character (in case there is only one).

You can achieve the second, using the following system (imagine that, instead of `x`, there's the number `1`):

```
=G1 * 2^4 + F1 * 2^3 + E1 * 2^2 + D1 * 2^1 + C1 * 2^0
```

This will create the following numbers for your cases:

```
8 : Some Text :  1
9 : Some Text :  2
1 : Some Text :  4
...
```

Combining both calculations gives you what you want.

Comment: I don't think you need to combine the two formulas, In O365 equivalent might be =SUM((C1:G1="x")*2^SEQUENCE(,5,4,-1)) and he should be able to just sort on that value, depending on what he wants if, for example, there are `x` in columns `f;g` vs a single `x` in column `e`.